# MS Access Database on Azure files system

Tags: azure, ms-access

I am trying to deploy an MS Access database on a Azure file system drive that is mapped as my z: drive however when I put my Back End Database on the Azure drive the database performs very badly even with the Front end on the local drive.  Can the azure drive be formatted as NTFS or is that not possible? The size of the drive is 5 Gig the Back End Access file is only about 90 MB or so.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Even though the drive appears as a normal drive, it isn't.

Access requires a normal SMB file share.

Comment: Yes Thank you so much working on getting that set up.

Comment: My IT people told me the share is setup as a SMB file, however when I look at the properties of the drive under file system it shows MAFS is that normal or should it say SMB or NTFS there?

Comment: It sounds OK: [Microsoft Azure File Service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service/) but I can't tell for sure if it supports Access 100%. Will try to look it up.